# Count transaction value for each user id

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions

I have a database that is used for recording transactions by customers.

The table (transactions) is set out as follows:

```
**ID | Added-date | userid | amount | department | transaction-date | addedby**

 1     yyyy-mm-dd   P1001    9.78     dpt 1        yyyy-mm-dd         username

 1     yyyy-mm-dd   P1023    19.78    dpt 2        yyyy-mm-dd         username

 1     yyyy-mm-dd   P1021    39.78    dpt 3        yyyy-mm-dd         username

 1     yyyy-mm-dd   T1501    9.78     dpt 2        yyyy-mm-dd         username
```

=======

What I would like to do is add up the total value of transactions for each user and be able to display the top 50 spenders.

Can anybody suggest a way to do this as I've drawn a blank so far.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try a `SUM` and `GROUP BY`?

Something like:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as `total_amount`, userid
FROM `transactions`
GROUP BY `userid`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid, SUM(amount) AS total FROM transactions GROUP BY userid
```

Having an aggregate function like `SUM` in your `SELECT` clause would normally cause only one row to be outputted containing the total from all rows matched by the `WHERE` clause. `GROUP BY` is a modifier for these functions and makes them aggregate per unique value in the specified fields.

See: [Group By](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the top 50 spenders:

```
SELECT userid, SUM(amount) AS TotalSpent
FROM transactions
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY TotalSpent LIMIT 50
```